# JMeter constant timers not operating as expected

Tags: timer, jmeter, constants

We have 3 distinct sets of requests that we wish to test using Jmeter.
For this we have created 3 samplers to house these 3 sets of requests and we have added a constant timer in each of these 3 samplers. 
Each constant timer contains the function "${__Random(X,Y)}" where X,Y are different for each of the 3 samplers.
However when I run the test I can see that for the first few minutes the requests look like they are being sent as per the timers, but after a period the requests come through almost uniformly accross the board which is not correct.

I have uploaded a picture that shows the structure of our test plan and the throughput that we are seeing [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6et1.png).

Answer (score 0):

The timers work as expected, I would say you're getting more or less equal throughput due to your application being overloaded and responding too slow, i.e. i can see response times over 40 seconds.

[image]

[HTTP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP) is a [stateful protocol](http://findnerd.com/list/view/Stateless-Protocol-Vs-Stateful-Protocol/662/), it means that JMeter's [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers wait for response prior to sending a new request so my expectation is that you're mostly impacted with response times, not the timers.

So if you replace your real samplers with i.e. [Dummy Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeters-dummy-sampler-the-ultimate-guide) with static response time of, say, 100 milliseconds

[image]

You should see your timers working as expected.

---

With regards to the application being slow I would recommend investigating the bottleneck, you can start looking at [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) and correlate the increasing load with the increasing response time.

Also make sure to monitor your application under test baseline health metrics, i.e. CPU, RAM, swap, etc. in order to ensure it has enough headroom to operate. It can be done using [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/) or [SSHMon Samples Collector](https://github.com/tilln/jmeter-sshmon#sshmon-samples-collector-)

Comment: Thanks for the response Dmitri. Currently I am using HTTP Request samplers that contain a method, path and parameters. if I replace the existing HTTP Request samplers, how do I replicate this using a dummy sampler as I cant see anywhere to specify these parameters in the dummy sampler?

Comment: You cannot test your application using Dummy Samplers, you can check if your timers work as expected using it.